# Querying UniProt and RefSeq databases with FASTA headers

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

This is my first post to StackOverflow. I've been playing with this problem for over a week, and I haven't found a solution using the search function or my limited computational skills. I have a dataset comprised columns of FASTA headers, Sequence, and count number. The FASTA headers technically contain all the info I need, but that's where I'm running into problems...

**Different formats**

Some of the entries come from UniProt:
tr|V5RFN6|V5RFN6_EBVG_Epstein-Barr_nuclear_antigen_2_(Fragment)_OS=Epstein-Barr_virus_(strain_GD1)_GN=EBNA2_PE=4_SV=1

Some of the entries come from RefSeq:
gi|139424477|ref|YP_001129441.1|*EBNA-2*[Human_herpesvirus_4_type_2]

**Synonyms**

I'd like to make graphs using count number vs virus or gene, and I thought it would be easy enough to split up the headers and go from there. However, what I'm discovering is that there's a seemingly endless number of permutations on the names of virus and gene names. In the example above, EBV goes by no less than 4 names, and each individual gene has several different formattings.

I used a lengthy ifelse statement to create a column for virus family name. I shortened the following below to just include EBV, but you can imagine it stretching on for all common viruses.

```
EBV <- c("EBVG", "Human_herpesvirus_4", "Epstein", "Human_gammaherpesvirus_4")


joint.virus <- joint.virus %>% mutate(Virus_Family = 
ifelse(grepl(paste(EBV, collapse = "|"), x = joint.virome$name), "EBV", NA))
```

This isn't so bad, but I had to do something similar for all of EBV's ~85 genes. Not only was this tedious, but it isn't feasible to do this for all the viruses I want to look at.

I looked into querying the databases using the UniProt.ws package to pull out organism name and gene name, but you need to start from the taxID (which isn't included in the UniProt header). I feel like there should be some way to use the FASTA header to get the organism name and gene name.

I am presently using R. I would greatly appreciate any advice going forward. Is there a package that I'm overlooking? Should I be using a different tool to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try to extract the Uniprot IDs from fasta headers and then do [programmatic access to uniprot](https://www.uniprot.org/help/api_retrieve_entries) to get xml files for that ID. Parsing these files with a package like xml2 can give you access to the Gene Name and Organism.

Comment: I think your best bet is to convert all your files to a single notation. All UniProt entries have the same form. All RefSeq entries have also the same form. Decide an ID type and translate each kind of entry to the decided format. At the end, all naming will be uniform and you will be able to work easily with it. Maybe you need to do some queries to the servers to get the proper IDs. Follow last comment guidelines.

Comment: In addition to pd0321 idea you can take a look at ftp://ftp.expasy.org/databases/uniprot/current_release/knowledgebase/idmapping/README to retrieve meppings of uni-prot IDs for your refSeq headers so you have an uniform ID to look up. If you need further help with any of this let us know. :)